# Neo4j new node on update

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, data-modeling

I'm new to neo4j/graph databases.
I am building a project with neo4j.

in my databases, it's very important for me to save changed that happen so I can analyze them after - my business-logic is looking for changes.

e.g. person A got Salary 10K after 6 months updated to salary 15K and after 10 months 20K and so on...

What is the best way to handle this in neo4j?

Is adding for every type of node in my graph an edge labeled USED_TO_BE with date a bad pattern?

what is the right way to keep track of changes in data? (creating a new node on every update)

Or maybe neo4j isn't a good use-case for me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot like a versioning question. You may find the [following blog post](https://medium.com/neo4j/keeping-track-of-graph-changes-using-temporal-versioning-3b0f854536fa) useful in your modelling decisions.